# is there a other way to start the console window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to open the console window in javascript. Pressing f12 will launch a program from Myasus. I would like to know if there is another way for starting the console?

I tried pressing F12 but this doesn't work.

Comment: Right-click on the website and inspect or open the browser menu and select the dev tools. You can also use Ctrl + Shift + I

Comment: https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole
> You can also use Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux).

Comment: @namgold  - That's interesting, I always thought it was Cmd+Shift+I / Cmd+Shift+J on Mac OS. I don't use Mac OS, do both work? Or was I just wrong? :-)

Comment: On my mac, cmd shift I open Mail app and does not do any effect on chrome either to open devtool nor console

Comment: Thanks @namgold! I've found primary docs saying it's Cmd+Option. I wonder how many times I've gotten that wrong... ;-)

Comment: See [How do I open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525).

Answer (score 3):

Other ways:

- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+Option+I</kbd> on Mac OS) opens Dev Tools (on most browsers)
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+Option+J</kbd> on Mac OS) opens Dev Tools and goes to the Console panel (on most browsers)
- Right-clicking the page and choosing Inspect (or similar)
- Using the browser menu to open Dev Tools

Here's docs from [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/) and [Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/index.html) for this, but most browsers do similar things.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use browser developer tools, which can be accessed by right-clicking on a web page and selecting "Inspect" or "Inspect Element." This will open the developer tools, which include a console window.